# Indeterminate Progress Bar won't disappear (Android)

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am executing an ASync task that is in charge of:

1. Displaying the indeterminate progress bar.
2. Loading a state from memory.
3. Removing the indeterminate progress bar.
4. Starting a new activity.

It is able to complete steps 1, 2, and 4 just fine, however when I use the back button to return from the activity started in step 4 to the previous activity, the indeterminate progress bar is still there! It stops me from being able to do anything, and remains on the screen indefinitely (it is not back in the ASync task, it is only the progress bar that remains). I am using setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false) and setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false) before starting the new activity, so I'm not sure why it's doing this. I even call these two methods in onActivityResults just to be safe! Below is my async task, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    public class LoadGameTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Integer id = params[0];
        try {
            GameManager.getInstance().setGame(id);
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("loadingFriendly", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

        //display the new game
        Intent intent = new Intent(offlineAct.this, gameAct.class);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 5050);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        ProgressDialog.show(offlineAct.this,
                "Loading Game", "This will take about 25 seconds.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to run .dismiss on the progress dialog create in preExecute